# Use asterisk as passive recording server

Tags: asterisk

We have a SIP trunk in our company. This SIP trunk is connected to Panasonic PBX and the PBX routes the calls to the extensions. Now we need a passive call recording server. The only task that this server should do is recording all the incoming and outgoing calls of the sip trunk and SHOULD NOT answer any call. So can we use asterisk as a recording server? If not what are other solutions?

Answer (score -1):

If you can connect it like panasonic->e1 card->asterisk->incoming/outgoing sip or panasonic ->sip(if your panasonic have it)->asterisk->incoming/outgoing sip - then answer is yes.

If you want it use like panasonic recording card - answer is no.